# Issue with @Output in angular

Tags: angular, events

​Hi i am trying to throw one event from  second component to first component but i am not able to get the event in my first component , but i am able to catch the event in the app component.Is there any limitation of this like we can only catch the event from child to app component only.Thanks in advance.

[image]

I am catching the event like this
​

```
<second-app (newEvent) = "onEmit($event)"></second-app>
```

Please find the folder structure:

```
           second.component
       first.component
app.component
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the @Output event processing for communication between a nested (child) component and its parent component.

To communicate between sibling components or unrelated components, you can use a service. I have an example service here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

The plunker is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

The service basically looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks It helped me to understand the limitations>